# how to cascade negative number in String form

Tags: java

For example, I have a string "-234254365356". Now I want to obtain the sign together with the last 4 digits, such that I have "-5356". How do I do it?

And how to do it efficiently for positive integers.

Below is my code. It works well for few integers. However, if I start inputting a lot of large integer in String form, tt returns me error.

I am reading from a TXT file, the `s` variable is a scanner.

```
 try{
        s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputTxt)));

        while(s.hasNext()){
            ArrayList<Character> integer = new ArrayList<Character>();
             number = s.next();  
                int i = 0;
                if (number.charAt(0) == '-'){

                    integer.add(0, '-');  
                    while(i < 7){
                        i++; 
                        integer.add(number.charAt(number.length()-i));  
                    }
                }else{
                    while(i < 7){
                        integer.add(number.charAt(number.length()-1-i));
                        i++; 
                    }
                }

                String disectedInteger = getStringRepresentation(integer);  
                dataList.add(Integer.parseInt(disectedInteger)); 
                integer.clear(); 
        }

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }finally{
        if(s != null) s.close(); 
    }
```

Comment: Please show us the error that is returned for large integers.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here.  But `Integer.parseInt(number)%10000` might do what you want.

Comment: There are two types of erros returning for different sets of large input integers (I have several files of txt files that have a lot of such big integers). One of them : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-219702-". Another error is ArrayRangeOutBound, which often occurs at second while loop, which puzzles me a lot, because i use ArrayList , it should be able to hold any amount of numbers, isnt it?

Comment: use the substring to get last four digit values.while you get the values ,check the if conditions ,it's greater than length 4 or not .

Comment: @user3608914 Note that your `java.lang.NumberFormatException` is thrown by code you haven't shown us.

Comment: I have editted the codes, i have input all the codes of try and catch.

Comment: #Duncan, to be honest, i am really new to programming. Self learning for few weeks. I don really know how to do debugging using catch. Would you mind giving me some information on that? so i can respond back to you better? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your original code can be simplified as follows:

```
    ArrayList<Character> integer = new ArrayList<Character>();        
    String number = s.next();

    if (number.charAt(0) == '-') {
        integer.add('-');
    }

    // Note: this assumes inputs are at least four characters long
    for (int i = number.length() - 4; i < number.length(); i++) {
        integer.add(number.charAt(i));
    }
```

A better approach would be to ditch your character list and move to a string builder:

```
    String number = s.next();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();        

    if (number.charAt(0) == '-') {
        builder.append('-');
    }

    builder.append(number.substring(number.length() - 4));
    int value = Integer.parseInt(builder.toString());
```

Alternatively, as suggested in the comments, you could get the same ultimate result by using:

```
Long.parseLong(number) % 10000
```

This approach will fail if the numbers are [too large](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE) to be contained in a long.

Comment: Yes, i am supposed to deal with 13 digit numbers and above. So, the long method does not work for me. Thank a lot for the input. I will try it out now.

Comment: @user3608914 Bear in mind a `long` can hold around 24 digits. But of course, if your input will be larger than this, clearly you need another approach.

Comment: @user3608914 See my edit above - your original code could be replaced with a string builder.

Comment: I am try to achieve as much efficiency as possible.So which of the two would actually work fast? Builder or string in this case? Thanks really a lot for the input. (I have millions of large integers for input)

Comment: @user3608914 I suspect they will be very similar in performance. If you are new to programming, you should read this: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: Thanks. If you allow it, can i ask one last question? Do you know any way of findng the first positive integer in this kind of long array in an efficient manner? My original idea was to input a Zero among all the large integers. Then i used arraylist.indexOf(0) to get there. Is this method good?(i have already sorted them in decreasing order)

Comment: @user3608914 Just do whatever is easiest to read/maintain. Don't worry about efficiency unless you've proven, with benchmarks, that this part of your application is unacceptably slow.